# Calculate the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have been trying to solve this integral which arises in a problem from the book Fundamentals of Differential Equations Nagle, Saff and Snider (8th edition - site 193-17).
   $$\int\frac{e^x \sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}\mathrm{d}x$$
The "progress" I made is below.

$$\int\frac{e^x \sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{e^x 2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{(cos^2(x)-sin^2(x))^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{e^x 2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^2(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^2}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{e^x 2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{(1
+2\cos(x)\sin(x))(1-2\cos(x)\sin(x))}\mathrm{d}x$$

also the if you take the following derivative (you get something interesting)
$$ u = e^x sec(2x) $$
$$ du = e^x sec(2x) + \frac{2e^x \sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}  $$

EDIT:
The original probem is to solve this D.E. with the method of variation of parameters.
$$y'' +4y = 2tan(2x)-e^x$$
Solution given in the textbooks is : 
$$c_1\cos(2x)+c_2\sin(2x)-\frac{e^x}{5} - 0.5(\cos(2x))ln|\sec(2x)+\tan(2x)|$$

Also the results i got were
$$v_1' = -\frac{\sin^2(2x)}{\cos(2x)}+\frac{e^x\sin(2x)}{\cos^2(2x)}$$
$$v_2' = \sin(2x) - 0.5e^x\cos(2x)$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this integral does not have an expression in terms of elementary functions

Comment: Use backslash before functions such as sin, cos, sec. It will look much nicer.

Comment: I've added the backslashes and also the original problem. Perhaps I've made an error before integrating? I would think that the problem set for this textbook would not include an integral that can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I suggest that you solve $y''+4y=2\tan 2x$ and $y''+4y=-e^x$ separately and add the solutions in the end, using linearity (the second one could almost be done without calculations). Show your calculations and we will see where it goes wrong.

Comment: i have the strong feeling that one needs something as frightening as hypergeometric functions to express the primitve in closed form

Comment: @tired, the integral in the top of the question, yes, but not the solutions to the differential equation further down, right? I'm cooking and looking after two children at the moment, so I can't give an answer in an hour or four.

Comment: @mickep you are absolutly right, the solution to differential equation might be obtained in terms of elementary functions. But i'm wirting up my PhD thesis at the moment, so my time for this site is also quite limited...;)

Comment: I tryed what mickep suggested and indeed I've got the right solution, thank you.

Comment: Mh, bad news, Wolfram invokes the Hypergeometric function with complex parameters.

Comment: How can I close this question?

Comment: you may delete it, just look below your answer.  btw why do you want to delete?

Comment: @JureVreča please don't delete good questions even when if you get the answer try posting the answer yourself , it will be always beneficial to the future stackers , and who know you may save a life or two .

Comment: very well then, ill keep the question open.

Answer (score 1):

If you  solve $y″+4y=2\tan⁡2x$ and $y″+4y=−e^x$ separately and then add the solutions using linearity you get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\bigg(\dfrac1f\bigg)'=-\dfrac{f'}{f^2}$ with regards to $f=\cos2x$, and integrating by parts, then employing

the fact that $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\cos2x}=\frac12~\ln\tan\bigg(x+\frac\pi4\bigg)=\dfrac{\ln\sin t-\ln\cos t}2$ where $t=x+\dfrac\pi4$ , we

are left with establishing whether $\displaystyle\int e^t\ln\sin t~dt$ and $\displaystyle\int e^t\ln\cos t~dt$ can be [expressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) in

[closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). This, however, seems highly unlikely, since another integration by parts results

in $\displaystyle\int e^t\tan t~dt$ and $\displaystyle\int e^t\cot t~dt$, at which point it becomes increasingly clear that what you

are **really** trying to solve is the differential equation $y~'=2\tan(2x)\color{red}\cdot e^x$, instead of the one

you were **actually** given.